# readv: Bad address

Tags: c, unix, system

In a library I am using I encountered `Bad address` error due to `readv`.

What is exactly the source of error?  Is it destination or source? 
Why does it not `segfault` instead?

Comment: Run with Valgrind, having the debug symbols ready, and then give more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bad Address` is the error message for `EFAULT`, which http://linux.die.net/man/2/read explains (the `read()` error codes are the same as for `readv()`) as meaning that `buf` is outside the addressible memory of your process. For `readv()` that means that either `iov` (possibly, but I guess that would cause a segfault, as it's only library-"interpreted" AFAIK) or, more probably, one of the `iov_base`-pointers (which are passed to the appropriate syscall to implement `readv()`) is outside of your addressible memory; `EFAULT` is the kernel way of telling you that a passed-in pointer for data exchange is invalid.

Check for `NULL`-pointers, or something similar, and as a commenter has said: `valgrind` can help you diagnose the source of the problem - in case you have debug-symbols available for library and user code.

Comment: was bad pointer - the library computed offsets using `int` rather than `ssize_t` ... sigh.